# cumulative product in R across column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in the following format

```
> x <- data.frame("a" = c(1,1),"b" = c(2,2),"c" = c(3,4))
> x
  a b c
1 1 2 3
2 1 2 4
```

I'd like to add 3 new columns which is a cumulative product of the columns a b c, however I need a reverse cumulative product i.e. the output should be

```
row 1:
result_d = 1*2*3 = 6 , result_e = 2*3 = 6, result_f = 3
```

and similarly for row 2

The end result will be

```
  a b c result_d result_e result_f
1 1 2 3        6        6        3
2 1 2 4        8        8        4
```

the column names do not matter this is just an example. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

as per my comment, is it possible to do this on a subset of columns? e.g. only for columns b and c to return:

```
  a b c results_e results_f
1 1 2 3         6         3
2 1 2 4         8         4
```

so that column "a" is effectively ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to loop through the rows and apply `cumprod` over the `rev`erse of elements and then do the `rev`erse

```
nm1 <- paste0("result_", c("d", "e", "f"))
x[nm1] <- t(apply(x, 1, 
              function(x) rev(cumprod(rev(x)))))
x
#  a b c result_d result_e result_f
#1 1 2 3        6        6        3
#2 1 2 4        8        8        4
```

---

Or a vectorized option is `rowCumprods`

```
library(matrixStats)
x[nm1] <- rowCumprods(as.matrix(x[ncol(x):1]))[,ncol(x):1]
```

Comment: Thank you, how will this work if I only want to apply it to certain columns? e.g. say I only wanted results_e and results_f so I only in reality need the column b and c rather than all of them? I'll edit my post to show I would expect the result

Comment: @user33484  IN that case select only those columns `apply(x[c(1, 3, 4)], 1, `

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try. Of the two approaches you have, which one would you go for?

Comment: @user33484  I would use `rowCumprods` as it is vectorized.  but you can check both the timings on your actual dataset

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = data.frame(Reduce("*", x[NCOL(x):1], accumulate = TRUE))
setNames(cbind(x, temp[NCOL(temp):1]),
         c(names(x), c("res_d", "res_e", "res_f")))
#  a b c res_d res_e res_f
#1 1 2 3     6     6     3
#2 1 2 4     8     8     4
```